# Valgrind - Error

Tags: c++, linux, visual-c++, valgrind

Below is the message I get when I run my code on Valgrind

1) Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
    ==16808==    at 0x400EC1: init() (Hite.cpp:90)

2) Invalid read of size 8

```
xmin=0.000000, xmax=1.000000, dx=0.010000, dt=0.000208, c=3.000000
==2763== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2763==    at 0x3E5420E836: __ieee754_exp (in /lib64/libm-2.12.so)
==2763==    by 0x3E54224A81: exp (in /lib64/libm-2.12.so)
==2763==    by 0x400F88: init() (Hite.cpp:96)
==2763==    by 0x4010C8: main (Hite.cpp:114)
==2763==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2763==    at 0x400EC1: init() (Hite.cpp:90)
==2763==
==2763== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==2763==    at 0x3E5420E8EC: __ieee754_exp (in /lib64/libm-2.12.so)
==2763==    by 0x3E54224A81: exp (in /lib64/libm-2.12.so)
==2763==    by 0x400F88: init() (Hite.cpp:96)
==2763==    by 0x4010C8: main (Hite.cpp:114)
==2763==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2763==    at 0x400EC1: init() (Hite.cpp:90)
```

How do we over come these errors from arising

```
90 void init() {
 91         double xmin=0;
 92     double xavg = 0.5*(xmin+xmax);


int main(int argc,char **argv) {
112     printf("xmin=%f, xmax=%f, dx=%f, dt=%f, c=%f\n",
113                     xmin=0,xmax=0,dx=0,dt=0,c=0);
114     init()
```

;

Comment: Can you show lines around Hite.cpp:90, please?

Comment: More code please, there's not enough to tell what the problem is.

Comment: Are you returning a value from the function?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience Added additional code

Comment: Looks like you need to show all the init() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to see the code but from the looks of it you created an uninitialized object on the stack:

```
double val;
```

You should change it to be

```
double val = double();
```

or

```
double val(0);
```

(I assumed `double` based on the size; it could also be a `long long` or some other type of size 8).

Comment: I am getting first error at init()

Comment: @user2588812: can you show the code causing the problem?

Comment: updated please check the main post

Comment: @user2588812: according to the error report, the issue is on line 90 which doesn't seem to be part of the code you quoted.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience Added additional code